# GAMS: Setting one variable to be equal to the second smallest of another vector variable

Tags: gams-math

```
SET i /i1 * i10/ ; 

VARIABLES
x(i)
y
;
```

I have an optimization (mip) problem where i need my control variable y to be equal to the **second smallest number** of `x`. **How can I create an equation to do that?**

```
EQUATIONS
myconstraint ;

myconstraint .. y =E= (second smallest element of x) ;
```

Comment: I am usually and R programmer and what i am looking for is something like this:

`y = sort(x)[2]`